Automate Analysis for Excel Prompts using VBA
I am trying to update the prompts in Analysis - which I do currently manually every month - for Excel; however, despite I am getting the value from technical name (which I guess is correct though), I can't change it with the code below:
Public currentDateRange As String
Public expectedDateRange As String

Sub GetInfoFROMVariables()

    currentDateRange = Application.Run("SAPGetVariable", "DS_1", "ZCALMDEF")
    
    '****Here the MsgBox currentDateRange retrieves the current value for ZCALMDEF, which is "2024/06 - 2024/11".
    MsgBox currentDateRange
    
    expectedDateRange = GetNextMonthYear() & " - " & GetFutureMonthYear(6)
    MsgBox expectedDateRange
               
End Sub

Function GetNextMonthYear() As String
    Dim startMonth As Date
    startMonth = DateAdd("m", 1, Date)
    GetNextMonthYear = Format(startMonth, "yyyy/mm")
End Function
Function GetFutureMonthYear(monthsAhead As Integer) As String
    Dim futureDate As Date
    futureDate = DateAdd("m", monthsAhead, Date)
    GetFutureMonthYear = Format(futureDate, "yyyy/mm")
End Function

Sub AtualizarPROMPTAnalysis()
    Dim Zeta As Variant
    
    Call GetInfoFROMVariables
    
    If currentDateRange <> expectedDateRange Then
        
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        
        '*****Here it does not work, neither the ARRAY or the expectedDateRange commands.
        'Application.Run "SAPSetVariable", "DS_1", "ZCALMDEF", Array(GetNextMonthYear(), GetFutureMonthYear(7))
        Application.Run "SAPSetVariable", "DS_1", "ZCALMDEF", expectedDateRange
        
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
        RefreshAll = Application.Run("SAPExecuteCommand", "Refresh")
    
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        
        'Here it shows normally what is expected "2024/07 - 2024/12"
        MsgBox expectedDateRange
        
    End If

End Sub

Technical name is checked, also I know it is ok because I retrieved this value with MsgBox currentDateValue normally.
I wrote and changed this code many times, using SAPCommunity, MicrosoftCommunity, StackOverFlow and ChatGPT as support, but did not succeed; not sure if it is a syntax problem or any other thing.
